# Proving the limits

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$ if and only if $$\lim_{h \to 0}f(c+h)=L$$

Now if $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$ then for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ Now as $x$ is tending towards $c$ so we can write $x=c+h$ where $h \to 0$ and so $c+h$ lies in every $\delta$ neighbourhood of $c$ so we get $$|f(c+h)-L|<\epsilon$$ whenever $$|c+h-h|=|h|<\delta$$ and so we get the result that $$f(c+h) \to L$$ as $h \to 0$.
Is the proof correct?

Comment: I think you should give the original task.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|x-c|<\delta$ iff $|h|<\delta$